# Setting default upload file permission in Filezilla

Tags: filezilla

How can I set the default **UPLOADED** file / folder permission in Filezilla? Such that I won't manually set the permission each time when I upload file / folder, thanks

Comment: Yeah there's actually a feature request with FileZilla for this since forever... http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/1920. But it seems default POSIX permissions may be a server-side setting, did you ask your the server admin? Did you figure this out? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found an apparently good tutorial here: http://buddingbloggers.com/2009/04/changing-file-permissions-via-filezilla/

As a side note, folder and file permissions are set on the server, you can use Filezilla, or you can login through a console if it's a Unix like system.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, but how about automatically change the permission when I upload a file/folder? Thanks